Sitecore XP 10.3.1 content updates on remote (replicated) CD server are always one version behind
QUICK SUMMARY:
We are trying to set up a remote CD server near China using SQL Server Transactional Replication.  We almost have it working but are noticing that when we update an item, the remote CD is always displaying the previous version of that item.
DETAILS:
We are trying to set up Sitecore 10.3.1 in a test env (before deploying this config to production) with the following VMs:

US CM
US CM database
US CD
US CD database
US Solr
China CD
China CD database
China Solr

The Web database is being replicated from the US CD database server to the China CD database server using SQL Server Transactional Replication.
Following the Sitecore docs, we have moved the EventQueue, Properties and Tasks table from the Web database to a separate WebShared database and have configured the CM and both CDs to use it.
We also have US and CN Solr instances with Solr Replication keeping them in sync.
Sitecore documents we have consulted in setting this up:

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0610106
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-sitecore-roles-for-separate-eventqueue%2C-properties%2C-and-tasks-tables.html

Here are some reproducible steps that illustrate our problem:

On US CM, update item to include "Test 1" in the content, save it and publish it
On US CD site, corresponding page displays "Test 1"
On China CD site, same page does not display "Test 1"
On US CM, update same content item to read "Test 2", save it and publish it
On US CD site, page now displays "Test 2"
On China CD site, page now displays "Test 1" (note that it is one update behind)
Recycle app pool on China CD site
On China CD site, page now displays "Test 2" (note that it now has the latest content)

We believe the China CD site learns that an item has been updated via the EventQueue table, which it seems to polls pretty frequently. We also know that SQL Replication can take a few seconds to push or pull changes.
We believe the following is happening:

China CD site gets notified via EventQueue.
China CD site immediately pulls the content item from the China Web database (before SQL Replication has updated it) and caches it.
User requests the page and gets the cached item with old content.

We tried a test where we waited a few minutes before requesting the page on the China CD site. And before requesting the page, we checked the item content in the China Web database and verified it had the latest content. But when we requested the page, we still got the old content!
Does Sitecore have any way to tell when the update of an item's data via SQL replication has been completed?  If not, it seems like a fundamental flaw to have the trigger mechanism (detecting an update in the shared EventQueue table) be much faster than the mechanism that transfers the actual data (SQL replication).  In our old Sitecore 8 env, we think the EventQueue and item data were both updated via SQL replication so maybe that's why that env didn't have these issues?
Any thoughts on how to resolve this?  We submitted this problem to Sitecore Support over a month ago and haven't made any significant progress towards a solution.
UPDATE 7/10/2024
We still do not have a solution for this.  It does appear that the China CD server is getting notified by the EventQueue and is using that trigger to immediately read from the replicated China Web database (which hasn't been updated yet) and storing old data in the cache.
We're still interacting with Sitecore Support on this but haven't gotten very far.  After several weeks, they did record our issue as a bug.  The only workaround they've been able to offer is a suggestion to increase how often SQL Server replication checks for changes and decrease how often Sitecore checks the EventQueue.  In our test env, we have SQL Server replication checking for changes every second (instead of the 5 second default setting) and Sitecore EventQueue checks happening every 20 seconds (instead of the 2 second default setting).  Even with those changes, about 10% of the time the EventQueue check occurs before the SQL Server replication operation is done.
In looking at the EventQueue notification, it seems like there's a good amount of metadata about the item being published.  One would think that the China CD logic could use that metadata to check whether the payload has been completely transmitted.  And if it hasn't, keep checking until it has.

I think what you are seeing here is caching issue on secondary CD. Sitecore official documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/104/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--replicating-the-web-database-using-azure-active-geo-replication.html#deploy-the-application-and-storage-roles have a warning message at the bottom:

On CD roles using replicated Web databases, visitor requests can potentially repopulate the newly cleared cache with old content, until the replication is completed. Sitecore is working on a solution to this.

Unfortunately, it is there from version 9 and Sitecore support did not help here as this is not their priority to fix it.
My advise here is first to create CacheClear.aspx page and add this to CD directly to determine if this is your actual issue and if it is you will have to come with custom cache clear event on item saved/published remote in delayed manner, by using timer or similar. Worth also to add some retry pattern like using Polly library to make it more resilient.
Official Azure geo-replication latency is 5s and backed by SLA so 5s would work in ideal world for sure to clear cache for Item https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/docs/view/Service-Level-Agreements-SLA-for-Online-Services?lang=1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1040341/how-to-monitor-azure-sql-db-geo-replication-latenc

Thanks Kamil!  We can confirm that the China CD cache is part of the problem.
Please see our original post for an update.
However, the Sitecore quote you listed appears to reference "visitor requests" triggering cache updates.  Our problem has to do with publishing (not user requests) triggering poorly timed cache updates.
